# Actions must be plain objects, How can i improve my action?

Tags: reactjs

i have this action, what is the error ?

```
export const edit = async (houseId, payload) => {
  try {
    await con.patch(edit(houseId), payload)
  } 
}
```

and i get this error: `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a lot of things. Actions should return a plain object or a function(as long as a middleware like thunk is configured)

**Do Something like**

```js
export const edit = (houseId, payload) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {    
    const apiResults = await apiHelper.post('my-backend-url', {houseId, payload}) //your code here
    dispatch({type: 'API_RESULT_SUCCESS', payload: apiResults})
  }catch(err){
    console.log('err', err)
    dispatch({type: 'API_RESULT_FAILURE', payload: {error: err})
  } 
}
```

[Check simple implementation of redux and thunk](https://codesandbox.io/s/z9p0mwny?file=/actions/actions.js:139-171)

[Also read this](https://medium.com/@lavitr01051977/basic-react-redux-app-with-async-call-to-api-e478e6e0c48b)

Comment: in this part te) => {// your code here} what should i put?

Comment: basically, you will need to install redux-thunk and configure the middleware... then you will need to make your api call as mentioned in the answer ... check the links , you will get an idea... still facing issue? share more code or sandbox or gihub link , i will have a look